# Creating a singleton for each instance of a class

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a python class, let's call it C. it takes a string in it's constructor. how could i make sure (design-wise) that

```
x = C('a')
y = C('b')
z = C('a')
```

this configuration leads to x and y pointing to different places, and x and z pointing to the same place?
meaning

```
x is y == False
x is z == True
```

Comment: Any reason not to just do `x = z = C('a')` ?

Comment: Override `__new__`, keep a dict of all instances created simply mapping `'a'` as a key to the instance, and return existing or new instances from `__new__` conditionally. Make sure you make that dict with [*weak references*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), otherwise those objects will never be garbage collected.

Comment: Can't you just annotate the class itself with `@functools.lru_cache(None) class C: ...`? I guess those would _not_ be garbage collected, but you can control the max number to cache (`None`/no limit here), but for many use cases this may be "good enough".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [WeakValueDictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) to keep all existing instances of your class in a dict like object on the class. In the `__new__` method you look up the existing object in the dict and if it exists return it, if not create a new instance and save it to the dict

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary


class C:

    __instances = WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = cls.__instances.get(value)
        if not obj:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            cls.__instances[value] = obj
        return obj

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

We use weak references to the instances so that they can be garbage collected when nothing else references them.

Comment: You'll want to pass args and possibly kwargs through to `object.__new__`…

Comment: @deceze `object.__new__ ` takes a single argument, the type to create an instance of

Comment: It *does* take additional arguments, your `__new__` does too. I just overlooked that they're passed through implicitly: *"If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])` [with the arguments] the same as were passed to the object constructor."*.

Answer (score 1):

One lazy way to do this would be to annotate the class itself with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
class C:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

x = C('a')
y = C('b')
z = C('a')

print(x is y)  # False
print(x is z)  # True
```

`lru_cache` is actually intended for caching functions, but it works with any callable, including classes, where it caches the call to `C.__init__`. Parameters must be hashable, of course.

This way, as far as I know, instances are *not* garbage-collected even if they are no longer used, but you could control the maximum number of instances to cache with the parameter to `lru_cache` (`None` meaning "no limit"), which might be good enough for many cases.